# Rails converting 1-9 to 1st September by default

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I dont know how but I am facing a weird issue where, when I have to print out `1-9` in csv, its printing out `1 Sep`. Any idea how this conversion can happen. I cannot paste the code for some confidentiality issues.

edit

```
fields.collect{|field|
               val=activity.send(export_fields[field])
               "\"#{(val).respond_to?('strftime') ? val.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') : val}\""
            }.join(',') + ',' + questionnaire_details(activity).to_csv
```

here one value of `val` is `1-9` other values like `200-500` or `100-4000` are also present

Comment: added a piece of code which i think is doing the stuff

Comment: It seems like whatever `val` is being assigned responds to the method `strftime`, although it's putting out the format '%d %B' and not the one shown above. Without more details it's difficult to help. It would be helpful to know the data type for the attribute being called as well as the the structure of the `questionaire_details` method to see if it's really an issue there.

Comment: no its not responding to the strftime, its converting some other way, is it possible somehow that 1-9 gets converted to 1 sep while generating a csv ?

Comment: are you converting the `field` variable to csv somewhere else? because it doesnt look like `val` ever gets converted to csv. Could you be seeing the output of the `questionnaire_details` method being converted to csv? Either way, I don't have enough info to help. Try calling `#to_csv` on the `activity` object and see if that attribute ends up switched to the offending output.